# Will require-dir scope my dependencies to each imported file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I'm building a gulpfile and have split up the tasks into different files. At runtime I'm `require`ing all tasks at once with `require-dir`: https://github.com/aseemk/requireDir.

The structure is identical to the gulpfile found here: https://github.com/greypants/gulp-starter:

```
// ./gulpfile.js
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
requireDir('./gulp/tasks', { recurse: true });
```

The tasks it imports look like this:

```
// ./gulp/tasks/browserSync.js
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var config      = require('../config').browserSync;

gulp.task('browserSync', ['build'], function() {
  browserSync(config);
});
```

So there's no `module.exports` or `exports.something`. Because of that, I'm wondering whether requireDir will still automatically scope the dependencies to each task. Does it scope my dependencies or am I putting everything in the global namespace when I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not required to use `module.exports` in a module. If in your second file (`gulp/tasks/browserSync`) you were to do this:

```
var localValue = "bar";

globalValue = "foo";

// and we never touch module.exports
```

Then node will create 1 local value which is not exported and 1 value in the global namespace, but that shouldn't be surprising.

If you were to do this in `gulpfile.js`:

```
var baz = requireDir('./gulp/tasks', { recurse: true });
```

Then `baz` would be:

```
{
    ...
    "browserSync": {},  // the default value of 
    ...                 // `module.exports` is an object ( {} )
}
```

And when you do this in one of your `require()`'d files:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
```

Then `require` will return a [cached response](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching), because it has already loaded `/node_modules/gulp/` before in your main file.

So yes, since you're not making global values (everything is prefixed with `var`), everything is kept contained within the task files themselves.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. What I still don't understand is: how can the required tasks be visible to gulp after using `require-dir`? If they're all in the returned object, wouldn't that just be inanimate? Wouldn't it have to be invoked in some way, like `baz.browserSync();`?

Comment: Well, every time you call `var gulp = require("gulp")`, you get the *exact same instance of Gulp* back, `require` has an internal cache. `gulp.task()` does `this.task[nameOfTask] = ...`. So everywhere you do the import, you have access to all tasks, because they're stored in the `Gulp` instance.